# Rails - How to query records in 5 different tables by user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have models `UserVote`, `Comment`, `Edit`, etc, all of which have a `user_id` attribute.  I'm trying to create a sort of timeline of recent activity, and this has me querying all 5 of my models separately and sorting by datetime.  However, with accounts that have a lot of activity, these 5 queries take a very long time to execute.  I'd like to find a way to optimize the performance, and I figured combining the 5 queries might work.

I haven't been able to come up with any working query to achieve what I'd like.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there an index on the "user_id" attribute in all 3 tables?

Comment: No, not that I know of.  Could you please explain a little about how that would work because I haven't found anything very helpful searching google for the last 5 minutes after reading your comment.  thanks

Comment: I have generally seen this done by adding records to an activity log, and then querying that. This has the advantage of letting you record arbitrary kinds of activity that may not correspond with adding or updating some other kind of record.

Comment: My idea would be to create a type `Activity` from which `UserVote`, `Comment`, etc inherit. By using single table inheritance, all data would be in one table. To transform your current data to that, you could use a migration.

Comment: On a side-note, what's with all of the answers in the comments, lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best suggestion in the comments is from Steve Jorgensen, with "I have generally seen this done by adding records to an activity log, and then querying that.".

If you want to take this idea to the next level, check out sphinx (a search engine designed for indexing database content). You can integrate easily with rails using thinksphinx - http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/.

Also, as Tim Peters brings up, you really should have indexs on all of your fkeys, regardless of how you solve this - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index.

Comment: +1 for Activity log solution, we can implement it with https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good idea to use Polymorphic associations for this problem - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class TimeLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timelineable, :polymorphic => true
end

class UserVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_lines, :as => :timelineable
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_lines, :as => :timelineable
end
```

Now you can sort time_line and access associated resources.